# Are there standard terms to say source was already cited (1) above (2) below?

Tags: citations, law

I screen shot pp 5-6, *Oxford University Standard for the Citation of Legal Authorities* (4 edn 2012). It doesn't answer question up in title.

I want terms for "already cited" 'cause I don't want to write down same source twice, but some authors always cite long form - even sources they already cited. But they never say they already cited it, and I write down the same source like 5 times until I re-read my notes. If they did, much time saved!!!!

> [image]

Comment: I added the law tag.

Comment: I thought the legal term was ibid?